# redirected to the login screen when I do a blank search

Tags: search

why when I'm offline , when I click the search button and not put any words I am redirected to the login screen?

I simply click in search button, don't put any word.
If i'm normal user, don't logged user, i go to login page.

I want to show a message: Search Empty, please try again.

Comment: Whats your search form. Like?

Answer (score 2):

The default WordPress behavior is to [redirect to the Front Page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11330) when an empty search query is submitted.

- What Plugins do you have installed/active?
- What additions have you made to your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: plugins active: Admin Bar Removal (3.1+ only) , akismet, All in One SEO Pack , ALO EasyMail Newsletter , Dashboard Commander , Efficient Related PostsFacebook Likes it! , Fast Secure Contact Form , Folding Category List (FoCaL) , Google XML Sitemaps with Multisite support , List Sub Categories Sidebar Widget , Login With Ajax , My Category Order , PixoPoint Menu Plugin , SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam , Subscribe to Comments Reloaded , Thoughtful Comments , User Access Manager , Visitor Maps and Who's Online, Wordpress User Frontend , WP-Polls , WP Hide Dashboard , WPML CMS Nav, WPML

Comment: I don't touch in my .htaccess , you have any idea how I can change the redirect to the login for a personalized message? example: <br> when I search a word and it does not exist
I see the search.php page with an error message

Comment: If the problem comes from any of your Plugins, I would suspect SEO-related Plugins first (as they are more likely to mess with search query results). Alternately, it could be a Plugin that wants users to login (thus being likely to redirect to the login page), such as User Access Manager, etc.

Comment: if I'm logged into the site and do a search without words , I see a results screen with all the articles from my site..I do not know if it was a plugin causing the problem

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can you disable User Access Manager, and see if the problem persists?

Comment: yes o try it now and disable Dashboard Commander too, no changes

Comment: What if you disable *all* Plugins?

Comment: ok i disable all plugins and i get search result page. I will try one by one to found what plugin do this problem i tell you.

Comment: well, when i disable All in One SEO Pack , and try a blank search, i get this erro: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/language-switcher.php:715) in /public_html/site/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897

Comment: You've got some poorly written code in the SitePress Multilingual CMS Plugin, that is sending header information prematurely (likely by printing some data that it should instead be returning).